# Qual è il significato di "punto e a capo" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Le otto montagne*, di Paolo Cognetti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Lara quell’estate aveva deciso di saltare un passaggio, eliminando il grossista che avevo incontrato anch’io e vendendo direttamente ai negozianti, anche se questo significava un mucchio di lavoro in piú per lei. Due volte alla settimana lasciava la bambina a Grana da mia madre e partiva in macchina per fare il giro delle consegne, e intanto a Bruno in alpeggio toccava arrangiarsi da solo; avrebbero dovuto assumere qualcuno, e sarebbero stati **punto e a capo**.

Non capisco del tutto bene il significato dell'espressione "punto e a capo" in questo passaggio. Sul [dizionario Garzanti](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=accapo) ho trovato

> *essere punto e a capo*, (fig.) non aver concluso nulla, dover ricominciare dall’inizio

ma non sono sicura su come usare questa definizione nel contesto del testo. Un po' più indietro nel romanzo appaiono queste frasi in riferimento alla coppia Lara-Bruno:

> Ma d’estate, vivendo lassú, riuscivano a essere autosufficienti o quasi; era d’inverno, con l’affitto della stalla e le altre spese, che non ce la facevano. Avevano dovuto chiedere un altro prestito. Debiti nuovi per pagare i debiti vecchi.

Quindi, il senso di "sarebbero stati punto e a capo" nel brano sopra citato sarebbe che avrebbero dovuto chiedere un altro prestito per poter pagare la persona assunta da loro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'espressione *sarebbero stati punto e a capo* vuol dire che si sarebbero ritrovati nella situazione di partenza, avrebbero dovuto pagare qualcuno per aiutarli ma questo avrebbe richiesto più denaro e quindi si sarebbero ritrovati con lo stesso problema.

Quindi la spiegazione che hai trovato su Garzanti è sicuramente corretta, anche se lo interpreterei con il fatto di ritrovarsi nella situazione di partenza.

Su Treccani si può anche trovare [daccapo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/daccapo/) che ha significato figurato molto simile a punto e a capo:

> **daccapo** (o da capo) avv. – 1. Di nuovo, da principio: *siamo d. alle
>   solite! Andare d., punto e d.,* o assol. *daccapo*, per indicare che
>   nello scrivere, nel comporre a stampa, ecc., s’incomincia una riga
>   nuova (più com. *a capo*); *cominciare d.*, anche fig., per esprimere la
>   volontà di ricominciare dall’inizio e di imprimere una direzione
>   diversa a un fenomeno, al proprio comportamento, ecc.